# Getting bluetooth data under Windows

Tags: .net, windows, bluetooth

I would like to use a certain device as a joystick.
With a zero-configuration DirectInput joystick connected via USB under Windows, I can easily get the joystick data for example with a timer like this:

```
Function joyGetPos Lib "winmm.dll" (ByVal uJoyID As Long, pji As JOYINFO) As Long
```

Now I would like to use [this device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NACKLKO) as such a joystick in order to process its data.

The description says that it's compatible with Android only.
But bluetooth does work under Windows, too.
So I wonder if I can get the data of this device under Windows.
I would for example like to know if one of the joystick buttons is currently pressed.

I have searched, but didn't find any information on this.

How could I access this data?

Comment: First at all you need to know what protocol it supports. Is it classic HID device or BLE? If classic HID you can simple pair with device and windows installs drivers for as a standard joystick. If it is BLE device you must develop own application. You can check it by running GattClient from Bluetooth Framework (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothFramework.htm). The demo app shows supported services. Next you have to find one that is resposible for buttons. If you have that device and it is BLE you can contact me directly and I\ll try to help with it.